# How prove this conjecture the exponent always is one

Tags: number-theory

When I deal with a problem, accidentally discovered a question below

> **Conjecture**: Let $p$ is prime number,then have
>   $$v_{p}(2^{\delta_{p}(2)}-1)=1$$

where $\delta_{p}(2)$ is the order of $2$ modulo $p$.and $v_{p}(x)$ is the exponent of the prime number $p$ in the prime factorization of $x$

For example:  $p=11$then $\delta_{p}(2)=10$,so $2^{10}-1=1023=11\cdot 93$,so we have$v_{11}(1023)=1$
and some other prime $p$ I found my Conjecture always hold.But Now I can't prove it

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime

Comment: it seem different problem,becasue $\delta_{p}(2)\neq p-1,\forall p$

Comment: Write $p-1=k\delta_p(2)$, and $2^{\delta_p(2)}=1+up^h$, with $p$ not dividing $u$. From $2^{p-1}=(1+up^h)^k=1+kup^h+.. $ (binomial theorem)and the fact that as $k|(p-1)$, it is not divisible by $p$, we deduce that $v_p(2^{p-1}-1)=v_p(2^{\delta_p(2)}-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture:
$$v_{p}(2^{\delta_{p}(2)}-1)=1$$

where $\delta_{p}(2)$ is the order of $2$ modulo $p$.and $v_{p}(x)$ is the exponent of the prime number $p$ in the prime factorization of $x$

A counter example: let $p=1093$ then $\delta_{p}(2)=364$ .
So $\qquad 2^{364}-1= 3\cdot 5 \cdot 29 \cdot \ldots\cdot 1093^2 \cdot 1613 \cdot \ldots <big>$
so we have $\qquad v_{1093}(2^{364}-1)=2$

A similar effect has the prime $p=3511$ and that primes are called "*Wieferich-primes*" after A. Wieferich who first detected this property with $p=1093$ (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime))

---

*Remark: perhaps you'll like this treatize which discusses a generalization but has been just inspired by the same as your observation: [fermatquotients](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf)*